# Can crashing a naked nucleus with a low energy muon reduce its proton number?

Tags: nuclear-physics, collision

I know that in many case, just crashing a naked nucleus with an electron does not reduce the proton number of that nucleus, but the electron just start orbiting the nucleus instead. I understand that this is due to energy conservation, as in some nuclei, the electron energy required is usually very high. Now, the muon is already a massive particle (around 210 times electron mass), which means, energy conservation is not a problem at all because its mass carry the required energy and the extra energy can be converted as kinetic energy of proton-number-reduced nucleus. I just hope dear members in the great community to explain for me if I'm right.

Comment: Search for muon capture.

Comment: A web search will reveal the answer.